# Need help in creating CSS selector for radiobutton group for selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, css-selectors

Below is html code, I need help for creating CSS selector, I tried using xpath but some controls are dynamic on the page which makes xpath vary on every other control selection.

```
<buttons-radio class="btn-group form-100 form-right ng-isolate-scope" options="trueFalseOptions" model="vehicle.CustomEquipment" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
  <label class="btn btn-default btn-sm form-50 ng-scope ng-binding" analytics-event="primary driver Yes" analytics-on="click" ng-click="activate(option)" ng-repeat="option in options" ng-class="{active: isActive(option)}">Yes </label>
  <label class="btn btn-default btn-sm form-50 ng-scope ng-binding active" analytics-event="primary driver No" analytics-on="click" ng-click="activate(option)" ng-repeat="option in options" ng-class="{active: isActive(option)}">No </label>
```

Comment: Please add HTML code snippet and more information to your Question.

Comment: I have added code already, not sure why it is not displayed to you. When I edit code is already there,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you want to **locate 'Yes' and/or 'No' labels under the 'buttons-radio' element.** The below css-selectors should work for you:

**1- For 'Yes':**

```
buttons-radio[model='vehicle.CustomEquipment'] label:nth-of-type(1)
```

**2- For 'No':**

```
buttons-radio[model='vehicle.CustomEquipment'] label:nth-of-type(2)
```

---

In case you're **not bound to use css-selectors, you can use xpath, alternatively** as below:

**1- For 'Yes':**

```
//buttons-radio[@model='vehicle.CustomEquipment']/label[contains(text(),'Yes')]
```

**2- For 'No':**

```
//buttons-radio[@model='vehicle.CustomEquipment']/label[contains(text(),'No')]
```

Comment: Thank you Subh, it really helped alot. Do you know any tutorial for xPath and CSS? I wasn't aware I can create xpath like this. I tried to use the hierarchical xpath

Comment: Glad it worked out. Please mark this as an answer.. Thanks.. :) On another note, this link will help you in forming relative xpaths, and css-selectors: [https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/xpath,-css,-dom-and-selenium-the-rosetta-stone/](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/xpath,-css,-dom-and-selenium-the-rosetta-stone/)

Comment: Thanks for all the help. This site looks really nice and explained everything. Thank you!

Comment: Don't mention it.. Cheers.. :)